# How to find the C# version of my Azure build agent

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I can build my code locally but the code will not build in my Azure pipeline. The build error message suggests my Azure build agent is using a different version of C#. How do I check to see what version it's using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the log of visual studio build task, you can search csc.exe, then you could find the path of csc.exe. Then you could check language version by calling `csc.exe -langversion:?`

VS2019 : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn`

Regarding specify the hosted agent dynamic, you could use [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cyaml-example#parameters) in YAML pipeline, then you could choose the image in Run pipeline form:

For example:

```
parameters:
- name: image
  displayName: Pool Image
  type: string
  default: windows-latest
  values:
  - windows-latest
  - vs2017-win2016
  - ubuntu-latest
  - ubuntu-16.04
  - macOS-latest
  - macOS-10.14

trigger:
- none


jobs:
- job: myjob
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.image }}
  steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: '.\csc.exe -langversion:?'
        workingDirectory: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn'
```

Comment: I think the only definite answer is to view the log of the build task in Azure. My team uses many different Azure build agents. By searching for csc.exe in the logs, I can see that one agent is using Visual Studio 2019 build tools and using the /langversion:7.3 parameter. Another agent is using Visual Studio 2017 build tools and using the /langversion:7 parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To check installed software on your build agent from azure devops go to:

`Settings > Agent pools > buid-agents > build-agent-0-1`

and go to `Capabilities` tab

Comment: There are a lot of "System capabilities" listed on that tab, but I don't see one that explicitly says the language version. Which should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

C# language version is determined by its target framework and Visual Studio version:

For every release prior to Visual Studio 2019, the default C# language version was always equivalent to **Latest Major**. In Visual Studio 2017, C# evolved and released three minor versions: 7.1, 7.2, and 7.3. However, new projects were still defaulting to C# 7.0. This proved frustrating for C# developers who wanted to use new features, but had to manually change the language version for each new project.

To address this problem, the default C# language version is determined by its target framework:

- If you are targeting .NET Core 3.0 preview, the C# language version
  will be C# 8.0 Preview.
- If you are targeting .NET Framework or any non-preview of .NET Core,
  the C# language version will by C# 7.3.

If you specify a language version via LangVersion in a project or props file, that language version overrides the previously described default.

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.0#csharp-defaults).

So you need to check your [specified agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU0zQ.png), target framework and the value of `<LangVersion> xx </ LangVersion>` in the project file to determine c# version.

As a workaround ,you can try to add `/property:langversion=latest` in MsBuild Argument of the Visual Studio Build task. Or since you can build your code locally, you can use a private agent to build using the local environment.

Comment: Your screen shot to check the specified agent shows the "Agent Specification" field on the "Run pipeline" form. When I run a pipeline, Azure does not show me that field. How do I find that?

Comment: If your pipeline is in yaml format, the "Agent Specification" field will not be displayed, the agent is specified in the yaml script. In addition, if you choose private agent pool, this field will also not be displayed. In the screenshot, I chose hosted agent pool "Azure Pipeline"